# How to suppress error message after cancel report print?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I used `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint`  to print a report. If I print the report, ok. But if I cancel, Access show a error and stop run the button code.

I used `DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)` but don't suppress this error.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the error code in your error handler, and if it's "Operation cancelled", ignore it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Something()
    On Error GoTo Trap

    'DoCmd...

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```