# ma access: sendobject on error go back to form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database that runs through with no issues, but when the user exits the email instead of emailing the report, an error appears. Right now the code shows:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "AUS_Main", acFormatPDF, "heather@gmail.com", , , _
     "AUS Checklist and Orders", "My AUS checklist and orders are attached."
DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll

    On Error GoTo Trap

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave

End Sub
```

I want the program to go back to the last form "15_End", if the user exits without sending, allowing them to make changes if they realize the report is incorrect. If they do send, I want it to continue as is, and quit the database.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062481/how-to-suppress-error-message-after-cancel-report-print/60063282#60063282

Comment: doesn't quite work. It still gives me the 2501 error pop-up if I exit the email...when the bottom part says 'resume leave' what does the leave part indicate?

Comment: The leave part is the exit from the procedure. If an error occurs, it's resuming the exit from the error handler. Can you please post the complete code?

Comment: Code works for me. Edit question to show your actual code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress error message after cancel report print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062481/how-to-suppress-error-message-after-cancel-report-print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the VBE is configured to break on unhandled errors.

> Tools >> Options >> General >> Error Trapping.

Then just manage the *2501 - Operation cancelled* error in your method:

```
Sub Whatever()
    On Error GoTo Trap

    With DoCmd
        .SendObject acSendReport, "AUS_Main", acFormatPDF, "heather@gmail.com", , , _
                                  "AUS Checklist and Orders", "My AUS checklist and orders are attached."
        .Quit acQuitSaveAll
    End With

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```